# Age Calculator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have this codes, this code must be able to compute the age of the user and It must be displayed on the text box provided and the age must change if the user changed his birth-date.
but this code does not work, it doesn't display the computed age in the textbox.

```
<input name= "date" type="text" readonly="readonly"  />

<select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  
 <option value="11/15/991">1991-11-15</option>
 <option value="10/23/1992">1992-10-23</option>
</select><br><br>
TextBox1<br>
 <input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"   readonly="readonly"><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
function run() {
  var birth = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
  var check = new Date();
  var milliDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  var AgeinDay = (check - birth) / milliday;
  var ComputAge = Math.floor(AgeinDay / 365 );
  var age = ComputAge / 365;
  document.getElementById("srt").value = age;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it?

Comment: There are way too much unnecessary code in your code to calculate age.

Comment: It doesnt show the answer in the text box

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/MBkVc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this..

```
function run() {
  var birth = new Date(document.getElementById("Ultra").value);
  var curr  = new Date();
  var diff = curr.getTime() - birth.getTime();
   document.getElementById("srt").value = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a look to complete Age Calculation in JavaScript:

```html
<body onload="getAge()">
  <h1 id="age" ></h1>

  <script>
    function calculateAge(dob) {
      var now = new Date();
      var dob = new Date(dob);
      var year=now.getYear()-dob.getYear();
      var month=now.getMonth()-dob.getMonth();
      if(month<0){
        month=now.getMonth()+12-dob.getMonth();
        year=year-1;
      }
      var day=now.getDate()-dob.getDate();
      if(day<0){
        var monthNumber=dob.getMonth();
        var fullDate=getFullDate(monthNumber);
        day=now.getDate()+fullDate-dob.getDate();
        month=month-1;
      }

      return year+" Years, "+month+" Months, "+day+" Days!";
    };
    function getFullDate(x){
      switch(x){
        case 0:
          return 31;
          break;
        case 1:
          return 28;
          break;
        case 2:
          return 31;
          break;
        case 3:
          return 30;
          break;
        case 4:
          return 31;
          break;
        case 5:
          return 30;
          break;
        case 6:
          return 31;
          break;
        case 7:
          return 31;
          break;
        case 8:
          return 30;
          break;
        case 9:
          return 31;
          break;
        case 10:
          return 30;
          break;
        case 11:
          return 31;
      }
    }
    function getAge(){
      x=prompt("Please Enter Your Date of Birth in format (yyyy-mm-dd): ","");
      x=new Date(x);
      document.getElementById("age").innerHTML="Your age is: "+calculateAge(x);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Wondering why you need `break` after `return`

Answer (score 0):

There were three errors in your code, see the comments inline below:

The year value of first option was 991 instead of 1991, might cause you to think the calculation is wrong.

String containing date that is being assigned to birth variable has to be passed as parameter to Date() function to create a date object that can be used with the current date object below it.

Variable milliDay was declared, then you were trying to use milliday (wrong case D).

```
<input name= "date" type="text" readonly="readonly"  />

<select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  
 <option value="11/15/1991">1991-11-15</option> <!-- year value was 991 instead of 1991, might cause you to think the calculation is wrong -->
 <option value="10/23/1992">1992-10-23</option>
</select><br><br>
TextBox1<br>
 <input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"   readonly="readonly"><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
function run() {
  var birth = new Date(document.getElementById("Ultra").value); //string containing date has to be passed as parameter to Date() function to create a date object that can be used with the current date object below
  var check = new Date();
  var milliDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

  var AgeinDay = (check - birth) / milliDay; //variable here was milliday all small case, declared above as milliDay with a capital D
  var ComputAge = Math.floor(AgeinDay / 365 );
  var age = ComputAge / 365;
  document.getElementById("srt").value = age;
}
 </script>
```

This will return the following values assuming the first option is selected:

age: 0.057534246575342465

ComputAge: 21

Are you just trying to get the age in years, or months, days hours too?

Comment: Im trying to get it on Years :)

Comment: Ok, then you just need the ComputAge variable, no need to divide by 365 :)

Answer (score -1):

Below is Advanced code for Age calculator in JavaScript

```
<h1>Age Calculator Tool</h1>
<h2>Hey Dear, What's your name? <br /><input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Your Name" autofocus/></h2>
<div id = "disBlock">
<p id = "disBD"></p>
<p id = "display"></p>
<p id = "time"></p>
</div>
<div id = "postCredit">
<p id = "credit"></p>
<a id = "about" href="#" target="_blank">Know More About Me</a>
</div>
<form>
<label>Enter Your Date of Birth: <input
type = "date"/></label><br />
<button type = "button">Calculate</button>
<button type = "reset">Reset</button>
</form>


<script>
let display = document.getElementById("display");
let input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
let button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
let time = document.getElementById("time");
let disBlock = document.getElementById("disBlock");
let disBD = document.getElementById("disBD");
let creditBlock = document.getElementById("postCredit");
let credit = document.getElementById("credit");
let about = document.getElementById("about");
disBlock.style.display = "none";
creditBlock.style.display = "none";
let dob = new Date(), today = new Date(), calTime;
function samay() {
let d = new Date();
time.innerHTML = d.getHours() + " Hours, " +
d.getMinutes() + " Minutes, " + d.getSeconds() + " Seconds Old";
}
function calculate() {
disBlock.style.display = "block";
creditBlock.style.display = "block";
credit.innerHTML = "Thank You For Visiting<br>Our website website.com";
let x = input[1].value.split("-");
dob.setDate(x[2]);
dob.setMonth(x[1] - 1);
dob.setFullYear(x[0]);
let year, month, day, HBD;
day = (function() {
if(today.getDate() > dob.getDate()) {
return today.getDate() - dob.getDate() - 1;
}
else if(today.getDate() == dob.getDate()) {
return today.getDate() - dob.getDate();
}
else {
let calDate = new Date(dob.getFullYear(), dob.getMonth() + 1, 0);
return (today.getDate() + calDate.getDate()) - dob.getDate() - 1;
}
}());
month = (function() {
if(today.getMonth() >= dob.getMonth()) {
if(today.getDate() >= dob.getDate()) {
return today.getMonth() - dob.getMonth();
}
else {
if((today.getMonth() - 1) >= dob.getMonth()) {
return (today.getMonth() - 1) - dob.getMonth();
}
else {
return ((today.getMonth() - 1) + 12) - dob.getMonth();
}
}
}
else {
if(today.getDate() >= dob.getDate()) {
return (today.getMonth() + 12) - dob.getMonth();
}
else {
return ((today.getMonth() - 1) + 12) - dob.getMonth();
}
}
}());
year = (function() {
if(dob.getMonth() == today.getMonth()) {
if(dob.getDate() > today.getDate()) {
return (today.getFullYear() - 1) - dob.getFullYear();
}
else {
return today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
}
}
else {
if(dob.getMonth() > today.getMonth()) {
return (today.getFullYear() - 1) - dob.getFullYear();
}
else {
return today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
}
}
}());
HBD = (function(){
if(today.getMonth() == dob.getMonth()) {
if(today.getDate() == dob.getDate()) {
disBD.innerHTML = "OMG it's your Birthday<br>Happy Birthday To You<br>";
}
else {
disBD.innerHTML = "";
}
}
else {
disBD.innerHTML = "";
}
}());
display.innerHTML = "Hi Dear " + input[0].value + ", <br/>You are " + year + " Years, " + month +
" Months, " + day + " Days, ";
calTime = setInterval(samay, 1000);
}
button[0].onclick = calculate;//when calculate button is clicked
function reset() {
input[0].focus();
display.innerHTML = "";
time.innerHTML = null;
clearInterval(calTime);
disBlock.style.display = "none";
creditBlock.style.display = "none";
}
button[1].onclick = reset;//when the reset button is clicked
</script>
```

More source code from : https://www.technicalarp.com/2021/11/javascript-age-calculator-script-html-code.html

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.